# Best way to loop through a table with queries and execute them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table which contains a column with queries. I need to execute them one by one and save the result in another table. What is the best way to implement this logic inside a stored procedure?

So for example the table looks like this:

```
id      query
1       select count(*) from table_a
2       select count(*) from table_b
```

A cursor can be an option, but is there another way?

Comment: Is the query always returning one row with one column?

Comment: You didn't specify the target table schema , which may influence the solution.  Does the target table have only one int column?

Comment: Are all your queries selecting count from tables - your sample data suggests that's the case?

Comment: It would be a small matter of Dynamic SQL.  However, you'll need to elaborate on the desired results/structure.

Comment: How do you want the result: each `id` with its result, or a sum total of all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try performing this task with a combination of `FOR XML` and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @mySchema NVARCHAR(10) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @stmt = (SELECT stmt FROM(
SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + CHAR(39) + s.name + '_' + o.name + CHAR(39) + ' AS TabName, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM ' + s.name + '.' + o.name
  FROM sys.all_objects o
  JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
  WHERE o.type = 'U'
    AND s.name = @mySchema
  FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 11, '') AS stmt
) xm)

EXEC(@stmt)
```

However, if only certain tables are required you will have to modify the query a little. Furthermore you can modify the query to get your selects from the table and join them via UNION ALL...